# Extract an attribute from a specific element in DOM

Tags: php, html, parsing

I want to be able to extract only the `src` of the second image in an html file. I am using the PHP DOM parser:

```
foreach($html->find('img[src]') as $element)
        $src = $element->getAttribute('src');
        echo $src;
```

However, I am getting the `src` of the last image in the page, instead of the one I am looking for.

Can I display only a specific `src` outside of the `foreach` loop?

Comment: You missed curly braces.

Comment: There is no method `find()` in PHP's `DOM`. Are you using SimpleHtmlDom?

Comment: What is `$html`? Are you actually using [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) instead of PHP's [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)?

Answer (score 4):

Your loop is missing {}, it is equivalent to

```
foreach($html->find('img[src]') as $element) {
        $src = $element->getAttribute('src');
}
echo $src;
```

so, the echo gets the $src after the last iteration of your loop, which is the last element.

Answer (score 1):

Using the example from their website, I'd go with this (braces are key here):

```
$count = 1;
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
   if ($count == 2) {
     echo $element->src;
     break;
   }
   $count += 1;
}
```